# How to process a list of .csv dataframe

Tags: r, list, loops, csv, export-to-csv

Sorry for newbie question here, What happened is I wrote a series of code to process one .csv data frame.

Here is what code (sample version)looks like:

```
MyFile <- read.csv(tk_choose.files(caption = "Choose CSV files from directory",),header = TRUE)%>% # 
 Select Input CSV Data
 transmute(A)%>% 
 summarise_all(sum,)%>%
 write.csv(file = choose.files()) # Output As CSV File)
```

and here is what output looks like in the Output CSV file:

[image]

But now I need to apply those series of code to a list of .csv data instead of one.

I managed to use the code:

```
temp = tk_choose.files(caption = "Choose CSV files from directory",)
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

to import those .csv files as a list, but is there any way that I can apply the same code
(ie.

```
transmute(A)%>% 
summarise_all(sum,)%>%
```

) to all the .csv files in the list and combine the result together? (ie.

```
            A
file1   658839755
file2   1541654313
file3   4643213843
```

)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply`/`map` over `myfiles` and apply the same code to each file.

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::map(myfiles, ~.x %>% transmute(A)%>% 
                     summarise_all(sum) %>%
                     write.csv(file = choose.files()))
```

However, this might be simpler

```
purrr::map(myfiles, ~.x %>% summarise(A = sum(A)) %>% 
                      write.csv(file = choose.files())
```

Comment: Hi Ronah, May i ask what is ~.x stands for?

Comment: @BomberGay It is a formula style syntax which is an alternative to anonymous functions which we usually use with `lapply` like `lapply(mylist, function(x) ... `. So instead of `x`, we use `.x` in `purrr`. Read more about this at `?map`.